# On iOS, the reply box can sometimes be covered entirely by the keyboard

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

The screenshots below are from Edge on iOS where it happens consistently, but this can also be triggered in Safari for iOS in certain circumstances, too.
[image: Now you see me,]
[image: Now you don't.]

I've put in a bug report with WebKit. Here is a link to the report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192402

Comment: Great. Apple never loved Microsoft. And there is no safari for windows phone

Comment: There was Safari for Windows at one point, and Apple always uses Office in its demos to show off productivity, especially on the iPads. I actually think the issue is a CSS/layout one, rather than a Microsoft vs. Apple one.

Comment: Hey, I'm just joking. To answer your question, yeah it might be a css related issue. There are lots of issues in edge's css processing. Layout, color, etc. Even if you try edge on windows 10, you can see those issues.

Comment: Actually, Edge in iOS uses Webkit, just like every other third-party browser in iOS.

Comment: This sounds like it's going to be a browser based bug, and not something SE can actually fix. Managing the input area so it's visible above the keyboard is a browser responsibility and not something web developers can interact with properly. In fact, we don't even know if the keyboard is open, and we don't know if the browser height we're being given includes space below the keyboard, and weird things will happen on other platforms and clash with their own input focus management if we try to do this manually. Try reporting to Edge devs. (Not staff, but another web dev who's seen this before.)

Comment: I've added a screenshot to help. I've also been able to make this happen in Safari on iOS.

Comment: I think this might only happen with non-default keyboards. (It should still be fixed, though. This is a major bug.)

Comment: What @doppelgreener says. I have the exact same problem with an in-house chat site on Chrome on iOS (and the iOS Webkit-based app for that). It's possible it's an issue with some attribute of the the input element, but more likely a bug with WebKit.